# Why isn't my Kurento kms6 install producing srflx candidates?

Tags: kurento, stun, candidate

I've got Kurento kms6 installed on Linux 14.04 box on the cloud, but I've had to open all my high numbered TCP ports to make it work across the internet (why it's not using UDP would be a different question I imagine). It's only generating host candidates, not stun candidates.

My /etc/kurento/modules/kurento/WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini file has the following entries:

```
stunServerAddress=217.10.68.152
stunServerPort=10000
```

I've checked that this stun server actually worked using

```
  https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/
```

It produced the following results:

```
 Time   Component   Type    Foundation  Protocol    Address Port  Priority
 0.002  1   host    1654867310  udp 192.168.0.15    53025   126 | 32542 | 255
 0.003  2   host    1654867310  udp 192.168.0.15    58843   126 | 32542 | 254
 0.103  1   host    740342174   tcp 192.168.0.15    9   90 | 32542 | 255
 0.103  2   host    740342174   tcp 192.168.0.15    9   90 | 32542 | 254
 0.167  1   srflx   2494774458  udp 24.68.32.13 53025   100 | 32542 | 255
 0.169  2   srflx   2494774458  udp 24.68.32.13 58843   100 | 32542 | 254
 0.169  Done
```

The kurento log has the following lines, indicating that it did see the stun server entries:

```
...

2016-12-02 19:48:43,956958 29738 [0x00007f819592a8c0]   debug KurentoLoadConfig         loadConfig.cpp:251 loadConfig()  Effective loaded config:

...
       "WebRtcEndpoint":
        {
            "stunServerAddress": "217.10.68.152",
            "stunServerPort": "10000",
            "configPath": "\/etc\/kurento\/modules\/kurento"
        },

...
```

When I stage a call, here is a set of the outgoing candidates messages in the log:

```
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,510623 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 2013266431 fe80::5400:ff:fe40:83d9 58273 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,510834 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 2013266431 fe80::5400:ff:fe40:83d9 58273 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,510983 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 1 TCP 1019217407 fe80::5400:ff:fe40:83d9 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,511116 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 1 TCP 1019217407 fe80::5400:ff:fe40:83d9 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,511230 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:3 1 TCP 1015023103 fe80::5400:ff:fe40:83d9 54928 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,511366 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:3 1 TCP 1015023103 fe80::5400:ff:fe40:83d9 54928 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,511490 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:4 1 UDP 2013266431 2001:19f0:5c01:f2:5400:ff:fe40:83d9 52252 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,511609 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:4 1 UDP 2013266431 2001:19f0:5c01:f2:5400:ff:fe40:83d9 52252 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,511744 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:5 1 TCP 1019216383 2001:19f0:5c01:f2:5400:ff:fe40:83d9 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,511877 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:5 1 TCP 1019216383 2001:19f0:5c01:f2:5400:ff:fe40:83d9 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,511990 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:6 1 TCP 1015022079 2001:19f0:5c01:f2:5400:ff:fe40:83d9 36476 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,512117 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:6 1 TCP 1015022079 2001:19f0:5c01:f2:5400:ff:fe40:83d9 36476 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,512255 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:7 1 UDP 2013266431 45.63.71.227 37948 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,512385 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:7 1 UDP 2013266431 45.63.71.227 37948 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,512510 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:8 1 TCP 1019216639 45.63.71.227 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,512622 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:8 1 TCP 1019216639 45.63.71.227 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,512757 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:9 1 TCP 1015022335 45.63.71.227 52956 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,512902 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:9 1 TCP 1015022335 45.63.71.227 52956 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,513014 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 2 UDP 2013266430 fe80::5400:ff:fe40:83d9 41890 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,513139 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 2 UDP 2013266430 fe80::5400:ff:fe40:83d9 41890 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,513261 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 2 TCP 1019217406 fe80::5400:ff:fe40:83d9 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,513372 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 2 TCP 1019217406 fe80::5400:ff:fe40:83d9 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,513496 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:3 2 TCP 1015023102 fe80::5400:ff:fe40:83d9 39536 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,513633 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:3 2 TCP 1015023102 fe80::5400:ff:fe40:83d9 39536 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,513750 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:4 2 UDP 2013266430 2001:19f0:5c01:f2:5400:ff:fe40:83d9 39416 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,513860 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:4 2 UDP 2013266430 2001:19f0:5c01:f2:5400:ff:fe40:83d9 39416 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,513971 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:5 2 TCP 1019216382 2001:19f0:5c01:f2:5400:ff:fe40:83d9 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,514078 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:5 2 TCP 1019216382 2001:19f0:5c01:f2:5400:ff:fe40:83d9 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,514195 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:6 2 TCP 1015022078 2001:19f0:5c01:f2:5400:ff:fe40:83d9 40403 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,514307 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:6 2 TCP 1015022078 2001:19f0:5c01:f2:5400:ff:fe40:83d9 40403 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,514417 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:7 2 UDP 2013266430 45.63.71.227 32947 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,514530 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:7 2 UDP 2013266430 45.63.71.227 32947 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,514636 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:8 2 TCP 1019216638 45.63.71.227 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,514760 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:8 2 TCP 1019216638 45.63.71.227 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,514895 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:9 2 TCP 1015022334 45.63.71.227 51971 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 2016-12-02 23:41:17,515022 31627 [0x00007fdbe9ffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:54 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:9 2 TCP 1015022334 45.63.71.227 51971 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1480722077","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"2dfd19fb-bbbd-4859-8183-3ce1b0a8f9db_kurento.MediaPipeline/b4b6451e-d40a-4e8a-b136-778190532877_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use a different stun server, this seems that is not working. Be careful when using this test page, as it already includes a sun server. I tested your stun server removing the default one and I haven't receive any srflx candidates.

Comment: I was careful. My suspicion is that you didn't get any candidates because you didn't press the "Add Server button" to add your entry to the list of ice servers. 
Here is a link to two pics that demonstrate that ice candidates were generated with just that ice server.
http://imgur.com/a/jhMwC